# Read a file of dictionaries as pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

The problem that I am dealing with is that I have a file (or multiple files) filled with dictionaries and I am trying to get then into a dataframe. An input file could look like the following:

```
{"A":"value1", "B":"value2"}
{"A":"value2", "B":"value3"}
{"A":"value4", "B":"value5", "C":"value6"}
```

Issues I am dealing with:

- Dictionaries are not separated by a new line or comma or anything. It's a one-line file and unfortunately, there is nothing I can do about it.
- Dictionaries could have a different number of keys. But I have the schema of the ultimate dataframe.

In the above example, the desired outcome would be:

```
A          B          C
value1     value2     null
value2     value3     null
value4     value5     value6
```

What I've tried so far:

```
spark_sql_context.read.json(path_to_file)
```

This only reads the first dictionary and returns a pyspark dataframe with one row. I have also tried reading it as a text file:

```
data_rdd = spark_context.textFile(path_to_file)
```

Problem is that I do not know:

1. how to split the line since there is no separator between dictionaries and
2. dictionaries have different lengths.

I'd appreciate if you could point me to a method or a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it as text then split by `}{` to get an array of JSON objects. To do this, first, we replace`}{` by `};{` then split by `;`.

```
df = spark.read.text(path)
df = df.withColumn("values", explode(split(regexp_replace(col("value"), "\\}\\{", "\\};\\{"), ";")))

df.show()

#+------------------------------------------+
#|value                                     |
#+------------------------------------------+
#|{"A":"value1", "B":"value2"}              |
#|{"A":"value2", "B":"value3"}              |
#|{"A":"value4", "B":"value5", "C":"value6"}|
#+------------------------------------------+
```

Now, use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) with your `schema` to parse json to struct:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("A", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("B", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("C", StringType(), True)
                    ])

df = df.withColumn("value", from_json(col("value"), schema)).select("value.*")

df.show()

#+------+------+------+
#|A     |B     |C     |
#+------+------+------+
#|value1|value2|null  |
#|value2|value3|null  |
#|value4|value5|value6|
#+------+------+------+
```